# Pop view from UINavigationController many times cause app crashes

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, crash, popviewcontroller

There is an item details screen where user can read all info about a selected item, and there is also an search bar in this screen where user can search for items then when they choose one, it will be displayed, because of complexity data, so I have to do this by pop current item view then push a new item view in.

Everything is ok when do this just some times, the problem happens when user do this about 25-30 times, app become slowly then crashes.

I guess that the should be a problem with memory but could not find out where it is.

Please help me on this, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide couple of screenshots of what you've built?. I need to have some idea of what kind of images and data you load in order to answer.

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak, have you checked this with instruments?

Comment: @deamonsarea: Actually the item view here is to display info of an instrument (stock), it has a some view with stock's info: quote, trade, orderbook. a chart view (CorePlot) and a table to display related news (there is usually 20-30 news)

Comment: Any huge images you're loading?.

Comment: @lnafziger: I am on this, thanks

Comment: @deamonsarea: I have just upload a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out where your memory grows. Then and only then you can find how to fix it. I'll give you few tips,

- Go to **Xcode -> Product -> Analyze** to find out what are the places you're having memory leaks and avoid them.
- Do more tests with Instruments also.
- Don't allocate big images using,

  ```
  [UIImage imageNamed:];
  ```

  above method will cache the image. Instead use,

  ```
  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:];
  ```

Comment: I did it before and fixed all warnings, but it seems the problem is just reduced, not sovled yet.